# How to Home Network Several Devices

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

## This is a little bit about Home Networking

I have this challenge that I want to connect all my devices to a home network(smartphone, laptop, tablets).

**This is the case:**

I have a laptop that contains all my files (songs, pc games, movies, ebooks etc.). This laptop has keyboard problem and is static as the case maybe;
Now, I want to create a Home Network scene whereby I can access any of these files (by access I mean, view, copy/download any of the files without an internet connection) WIRELESSLY from any of my devices (smartphone, tablet, pcs) when they connect to the laptops' Network.

**So, it'll be more like**

PC, tablet, and phone connects to the static laptop Network, then searches through and then copy any file(s) that is inside that static latop.

I've heard and tried HomeGroup that comes with windows, but i think it's only limited to PC and PC connectivity and other devices(phones) can not access it

*Please, is this my request possible, even if it requires a third party software? if YES, let me know so i can get it started...pls*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the most part you need to get a router to do the wireless link. Usually laptops cant hotspot for multiple devices. Then its a matter of setting up the firewall permissions on the laptop and allowing access to the shares.

As far as the home group question, if you instead set yourself up as a workgroup Win7 Pro/Ultimate should not have a homegroup limitation.

Check 
System Properties - Advanced System Properties - Computer Name Tab - and click the Change button.

Edit: 
This link looks like it has what you need including apps to try.  I can say for certain that VLC doesn't have a native method to perform this task. 
http://www.howtogeek.com/191378/how-to-access-shared-windows-folders-on-android-ipad-and-iphone

Comment: The laptop runs on windows 7 ultimate 64bit

Comment: I'm not sure why that was down voted but whatever. Win 7 Ultimate will handle acting as a home server. If you want to simplify your life, put all of the folders you want to share under one tree and then right click on it, select Properties, and then go to the Sharing tab. If you want everyone who has access to your network to have access to those files, add the special user keyword  'Everyone' with read permissions.

Comment: Yea,am aware if that system,but the question is, would devices such as smartphones and tablets be able to access the shared folders? For pc,i have done something like that before,just that now,smartphone is involved...thanks though

Comment: You should update your original question with that more specific clarification then.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: I checked out the link, and i think that link pretty much answers my question...i will give a feedback once i have tried it...thanks again for the link

Comment: Not really, the link answered my question...thats all